# Cannot access sqlbuddy on nginx server

Tags: linux, nginx, sqlbuddy

I installed sqlbuddy following the guide by [arstechnia](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/12/web-served-part-4-get-your-database-on/), but I cannot seem to access sqlbuddy.

This is the setup for /etc/nginx/sites-available/www

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                allow 192.168.1.0/24;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                deny all;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            allow 192.168.1.0/24;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            deny all;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass php5-fpm-sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            }
        location ~ /\. {access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }
        location ~ ~$ {access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }
        location ~ /sqlbuddy/.*\.php$ {
            allow 192.168.1.0/24;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            deny all;
            try_files $uri =404;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass php5-fpm-sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        }

}
```

When I try to access sqlbuddy via 192.168.1.128/sqlbuddy I get this page from chrome:
http://imgur.com/8pomz3m

Nginx access log shows no record of me trying to access sqlbuddy but does record me accessing the index page and 192.168.1.128/phpinfo.php

No errors present in nginx error log either.

I tried individually commenting sections of the location ~ /sqlbuddy/... to no avail. Really lost on this one.

Comment: Is your nginx actually running locally on your very own computer?

Answer (score 2):

Following the same guide I came across with the same problem.

I commented out the location that made all requests to sqlbuddy go through https, I see you don't have it so it shouldn't be a problem.

Try **deleting the browser's cache**. That dit it for me.

Hope it helps.-

Answer (score 0):

Check your sqlbuddy folder structure, make sure your index is in /sqlbuddy/index.php and not in /sqlbuddy/src/index.php. I had to copy all sources to /sqlbuddy.

also check your permission and owner for sqlbuddy (www-data:www-data).